# How do I stop Joomla from including jQuery?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I've recently upgraded from Joomla 3.2.1 to Joomla 3.2.2.

In Joomla 3.2.1, I manually unset jQuery from being included:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

$dontInclude = array(
'/media/jui/js/jquery.js',
'/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js',
'/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js',
'/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.js',
'/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js',
'/media/jui/js/bootstrap.js',
'/media/system/js/core-uncompressed.js',
'/media/system/js/tabs-state.js',
'/media/system/js/core.js',
'/media/system/js/mootools-core.js',
'/media/system/js/mootools-core-uncompressed.js',
);
foreach($doc->_scripts as $key => $script){
    if(in_array($key, $dontInclude)){
        unset($doc->_scripts[$key]);
    }
}
```

But this isn't working in Joomla 3.2.2. Is there a way to not include Joomla's jQuery in 3.2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added:

```
            $doNotInclude = array(
                'jquery',
                'bootstrap',
                'behavior',
            );
            if(in_array($file, $doNotInclude)){
                return;
            }
```

immediately after:

```
            list($key, $prefix, $file, $func) = static::extract($key);
```

in libraries/cms/html/html.php, in the "_" function.

I don't like it since its a modification to the Joomla core but it works. I'm still looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 5):

Another variation which works well for me with Joomla 3.4 is to edit the template > index.php file with something like:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

$headData = $doc->getHeadData();
$scripts = $headData['scripts'];

//scripts to remove, customise as required

unset($scripts[JUri::root(true) . '/media/system/js/mootools-core.js']);
unset($scripts[JUri::root(true) . '/media/system/js/mootools-more.js']);
unset($scripts[JUri::root(true) . '/media/system/js/core.js']);
unset($scripts[JUri::root(true) . '/media/system/js/modal.js']);
unset($scripts[JUri::root(true) . '/media/system/js/caption.js']);
unset($scripts[JUri::root(true) . '/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js']);
unset($scripts[JUri::root(true) . '/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js']);
unset($scripts[JUri::root(true) . '/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js']);
unset($scripts[JUri::root(true) . '/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js']);

$headData['scripts'] = $scripts;
$doc->setHeadData($headData);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a prefix of `JUri::root(true)` before each of those file names - relative paths will not work

Comment: If I dump the $doc->_scripts array, its empty. I think the issue is that Joomla changed how its including scritps

Comment: I've just checked my 3.2.2 and it IS populated. Where are you making this check? In a template or extension or what?

Comment: I'm making the check at the top of the template's index.php... it was populated there before I upgraded, I'm not sure why its not populated now

Comment: I have no clue. Try unzipping the update files again. Perhaps something went wrong in the upgrade. If the css files are being included though the script HAS to be populated at some point

Answer (score 1):

You can also try something like this:

```
$removeScripts = [
    '/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js',
    '/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js',
    '/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js',
    '/media/system/js/caption.js',
];
foreach ($removeScripts as $removeScript) {
    unset($this->_scripts[JURI::root(true).$removeScript]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `in_array`.

If you remove it by changing this:

```
foreach($doc->_scripts as $key => $script){
    if(in_array($key, $dontInclude)){
        unset($doc->_scripts[$key]);
    }
}
```

to this:

```
foreach($doc->_scripts as $key => $script){
    unset($doc->_scripts[$key]);
}
```

Then it works fine. It's pretty pointless checking if the array key exists as I gathered you haven't manually deleted any of these files yourself.

Hope this helps

Comment: The problem is its not hitting that loop at all, since $doc->_scripts is an empty array

Comment: Try using `JUri::root() . 'media/....'` to define the paths. If this doesn't work, unless you have deleted the files manually, I'm not sure how it can be an empty string as I have just literally tested this myself on Joomla 3.3.2

Comment: I've dumped the $doc object and there is nothing in the scripts array.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla 3.3.6 loads scripts in different way so $doc->_scripts will return nothing... so there is nothing to unset.

I recommend to use this plugin: https://github.com/Poznakomlus/joomla_options

It allows you to remove bootstrap, jQuery and mootools (you can choose what to disable).

Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated any way with plugin developer or plugin itself in any way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a custom template or a component, where you need to remove all the scripts loaded by default inside Joomla you can create a simple plugin and bind the execution to the `onBeforeCompileHead` event.

My implementation was as below. Its very simple. You can further play around with the search list, by being specific to file names or just plain blacklisting the parent folder.

```
protected $app;
public function onBeforeCompileHead() {
    // Front end
    if ($this->app instanceof JApplicationSite) {
        $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
        $search = array(
            'jui/js/',
            'system/js/'
        );
        foreach ($doc->_scripts as $key => $script) {
            foreach ($search as $findme) {
                if (stristr($key, $findme) !== false) {
                    unset($doc->_scripts[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PHP Manual says: **Note: If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead.**

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in joomla 3.9

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
$unset_scripts = [
    '/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js',
    '/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js',
    '/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js',
    '/media/system/js/caption.js',

];
foreach ($unset_scripts as $script) {
    unset($this->_scripts[JURI::root(true) . $script]);
}
if (isset($this->_script['text/javascript'])) {
    $captionJsStr = '%jQuery\(window\)\.on\(\'load\',\s*function\(\)\s*{\s*new\s*JCaption\(\'img.caption\'\);\s*}\);\s*%';
    $this->_script['text/javascript'] = preg_replace($captionJsStr, '', $this->_script['text/javascript']);
    if (empty($this->_script['text/javascript'])) {
        unset($this->_script['text/javascript']);
    }

}
$this->_scripts = array();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Since you guarantee that `$this->_script['text/javascript']` will be declared, `if (empty())` is inappropriate.  `if (!$this->_script['text/javascript'])` does the same thing.